# Socket.io Enable Multicasting Inside Rooms

Tags: node.js, socket.io

If I have 4 users : a,b,c and I have socket.io room grouping those users

```
room: {a,b,c,d}
```

So In the last room if `a` emit an event all the users will be notified about this event but if user `b` send a message user `c` **should not** get notified about this event.

Also when user `c` emit an event user `g` should not get notified about this event but they both shout get notified when user `a` or `d` emit an event.

Is there any way to achieve that withing to `socket.io` rooms API or I should use a different approach

*note:* I don't want to join the users to multiple rooms because every group of users should be organized in one room

Comment: What determines if a user should or should not get notified?

Comment: there is rules stored in a DB and it can be fetched when the application want these rules.

Comment: such way doesn't exist , socket.io can't determinate "which room will get what" based on rules in database, you can write a function that can do all the work, and emit to correct rooms.